# DRV8871 (DC-Motor Driver) extremely reduced output voltage

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, i2c, h-bridge, motor-controller

I am working on a PCB which contains a PCA9685 PWM Driver and four DRV8871 motor drivers. The basic idea of the board is the PCA is controlled by a micro via I2C which then creates a PWM signal sent to the DRVs which then drive a bunch of BDC motors. I actually have already made one of these boards to drive 3 motors and it works a treat however after adapting it to 4 motors I am running into a strange issue.

The I2C signal going into the PCA is clean and the PCA is able to generate the desired PWM signals. This PWM signal is fed into the DRV however the DRV output is a tiny signal (nowhere near the 12V that is being provided to it).

Here is the schematic and the board layout:

[image: Full board schematic]

[image: Full board layout (note the bottom layer is a ground plane and a few signals for the encoders)]

I have run a number of tests to try and determine the issue:

1. I bypassed the motor drivers and sent the PWM signal from the PCA directly to a DRV8871 motor driver breakout board (made by adafruit) however the breakout board showed the exact same signal on the DRV output as was seen on my board.
2. I bypassed the PCA by using a breakout board (also adafruit) however this also showed no change to the signal coming from the DRV
3. I soldered a 47uF cap directly to pin 5 (power) on one of the DRVs to see if it was a power delivery issue but that had no effect

Now for the signals from the board. All these tests are done with only the PCB (no external breakout boards) however the tests mentioned previously had identical results. In this capture you can see Chanel 1 (Yellow) is on the output pin of one of the DRVs and has a amplitude of 300mV (varying from -20mV to -300mV). Channel 2 (Blue) is the PWM output from the PCA which is as expected, 50% duty cycle at 3.3V. Channel 3 and 4 are the SCL and SDA lines respectively and are sending data to the PCA accurately.

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated. It has me very confused since an identical design (albeit with one less motor driver) works exactly as expected. Incase it is of any help here is a picture of the board in question (bodge wired up as I've been trying to diagnose it). And also a picture of the working 3 motor version (I removed the PCA on this one to test if the chip was broken on the 4 motor board).

[image: 4 Motor Driver Board, not working with a lot of extra wires for testing]
[image: 3 Motor Driver Board (missing PCA but otherwise it works)]

Comment: Probe/Measure until you figure out which component is improperly dropping the bulk of the supply voltage across itself and causing the bulk of the voltage drop to not be across the motor.  If it's the top or bottom of the bridge, figure out why.  Are there unsoldered pins?  Blown channels?  And of course make sure you don't have a 1x vs 10x mixup with your probe settings.

Comment: @ChrisStratton at this point I'm fairly certain the drop is across the bridge since there is a clean 12V on the Vcc pin but the output is obviously not there. That said, I had tested with an external board that I know works and it had the same issue which is why I don't think it's a matter of there being unsoldered pins/blown channels/etc. At this point the only thing I can think of is the layout of my filter caps could be closer to the power pin and so there is some instability because of that (although even then I tried directly soldering a 47uF to it and that didn't help)

Comment: @soup, Ah, let me see, if (1) Three pwm signals PWM-A, PWM-B, PWM-C to three drivers: DRV-A, DRV-B, DRV-C working OK, but (2) Now adding additional PWM-D to DRV-D causes trouble, then (3) We can we can troubleshoot by swapping any one of A, B, C with D and if also OK, then obviously it the not the DRVs problem, and should be some sort of "overloading" problem. (4) And if the same PWM-X to all 4 DRVs has the same problem, then obviously it is the PCB problem, (5) Perhaps you can replace 4 motors by 4 resistors and see if problem disappears.

Comment: @tlfong01 I've probed with motors resistors and nothing connected to the PWM-X pins but the issue persists, I am beginning to think it may be some sort of interference problem possibly due to the drivers being much closer on the 4-Motor board vs the 3-motor board. The newer revision of the board is 4 layer (woo JLCPCB sale) and we'll see if that helps.

Comment: @soup, I am also playing with DRV8871 and might catch up you soon: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531470/how-to-troubleshoot-a-drv8833-motor-driver-module-problem/531522#531522. I am using cheapy AliExpress/TaoBao DRV8871 modules on proto boards and so far so good. My long term plan is making a 4 motor 4WD car. Please let me know if you are still waiting for the new PCB, and any progress so far. Have a great project. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 thought I should update, I got a 4 layer version of the board and everything seems to be working as expected. It seems the issue was EMI.

Comment: @soup. Thank you very much for your update. That is a very helpful troubleshooting tip for my future projects using multiple layer PCBs. Cheers.