# DRV8870 motor driver not powering motor

Tags: motor, driver, h-bridge, motor-controller, vibration-motor

I am fairly new to electronics.

I am trying to control a single 1.5V encapsulated vibration motor with the DRV8870 motor driver without much success. The motor is connected to the circuit at CN1 with a 3.7V LiPo battery connected at CN2 as power source.

In researching how H-bridges work, even prior to coding, here are my suspicions:

1. Looking at the schematic (highlighted in pink,) I noticed that the DRV8870's IN1 pin is connected to GND as opposed to an I/O pin like IN2. Is this an issue?
2. Looking at the DRV8870 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8870.pdf?ts=1620014775564&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F), I noticed that the operating voltage starts at 6.5V. Maybe the driver also isn't getting enough volts to even turn on.

Hoping someone with more experienced eyes can confirm my suspicions and/or offer guidance on altering the design/components to make this work.

[image]

Comment: Where are those schematics from?

Comment: My answer to an DRV8833 question might help a bit: 

How to troubleshoot a DRV8833 motor driver module problem? - EESE 2020nov09
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531470/how-to-troubleshoot-a-drv8833-motor-driver-module-problem.

Comment: Your motor voltage specifies 1.5V power, that might be too low for the specified 2.7V min of DRV88xx. You might try to test a 3V3 or 5V0 motor and see if it works.