# Simplest possible test for a DRV8833 motor controller

Tags: motor-controller

I'm working with a [DRV8833](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8833.pdf) motor controller, a long way from my intended solution of controlling using a Raspberry Pi for which there are many resources out there.

I am stuck however on a breadboard with a DRV8833 connected to a battery/regulator as per [How to troubleshoot a DRV8833 motor driver module problem?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531470/how-to-troubleshoot-a-drv8833-motor-driver-module-problem) where I can't get *anything* out of out1/out2.

Vcc/Ground are connected and tested since they can power an LED, In1/In2 are connected (Vcc & Ground) and tested since they also power an LED when connected. Nothing happens on Out1/Out2.

My only thought which is referred to on the linked question is what to do with EEP, but none of leaving floating, connecting to Vcc or Ground are doing anything for me.

I understand that this is plummeting towards being a very poorly constructed question, so in my defence:

1. I believe I have soldered the DRV8833 appropriately, and tested for continuity using a multimeter, and also checked against adjacent pins being shorted
2. The power supply is a 9 V battery connected through a regulator which came as part of a kit which i've tested at the two options of 3.3 V and 5 V with the same results.
3. I have resorted to very primitive testing using LEDs and multi-meter to prove voltage

What's the simplest and most foolproof way to demonstrate that a DRV8833 on a breadboard is working?

Comment: connect a motor ... incandescent lamp, if motor  is not available

Comment: what kind of a 9 V battery are you using?

Comment: A household 9V battery.

Comment: that won't run a motor for very long

Comment: I don't need it to :-) I'm just trying to prototype my first electronics project in a very long time! I have a seperate USB powered voltage regulator that I plan to use once finished.